# VS.NET 2010 Output window show the stored procedure call - Debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am not able to recall the steps to expose the SP call at runtime in the output window under the debug mode. I am working on asp.net web forms project.

I am sure there is a way to see the SP call execution in the output window, but somehow missing the steps to configure it.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Debug.WriteLine("Any useful data") and string "Any useful data" will appear in your output window. You can write your SP name, parameters and result there and see it during debug.

Also you can use IntelliTrace to see all ADO.NET calls including SP.
Open IntelliTrace window during debug and filter ADO.NET events.

Comment: can we get the entire SP call also?

Comment: what do you mean "get entire SP call"? give an example of what you wnat to see

Comment: I once saw the entire SP call like this Exec <sp_name> @parameters in the output window.